# Using Spark Dataproc to write in Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, streaming, google-cloud-pubsub, dataproc

I want to use Dataproc Spark to run 2 SQL files on BigQuery that are executed each minute, and then write the results into pub/sub.
I am not sure if I can use these two technologies together.
Does anyone that already have used Dataproc with Pub/Sub on GCP confirm to me if it's possible..

Answer (score 0):

After your [cluster creation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/quickstarts), you can use [BigQuery connector with Spark](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example#pyspark) to execute the SQL queries on BigQuery. The [spark-bigquery-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector) with **Apache Spark** can read and write data from and to BigQuery.

Create a `Pub/Sub Lite topic` to write results into Pub/Sub. ["Write Pub/Sub Lite messages by using Apache Spark"](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/lite/docs/write-messages-apache-spark) can be used. This can **read and write** messages to **Pub/Sub Lite** using `PySpark` from a `Dataproc Spark cluster`.

Be sure to have the necessary dependencies to interact with BigQuery and Pub/Sub. Remember that you need to ensure proper authentication and authorization to access BigQuery and Pub/Sub resources from your Spark job.